# Am I using the next.js Head element wrong?

Tags: next.js, favicon, head

Try as I might, I can't seem to get Next.js to recognize its own Head information. It recognizes the title, but that's all. Neither the meta data or favicon make it to render. This is a single page application. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../components/App';
import Head from 'next/head';

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <Head>
                    <title>My page title</title>
                    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../public/assets/favicon.ico"/>
                    <meta property="og:title" content="My page title" key="title" />
                </Head>

                <App></App>
                <style>
                    {`
                          html, body, #__next {
                            margin: auto;
                            margin-top: 0;
                            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                            background-color: #282c34;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                            overflow: hidden;
                          }
                    `}
                </style>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Partially figured it out myself. Turns out it was a combination of google chrome not wanting to update its cache, and not understanding how to use `href="/image.ico"`. It was unclear to me that the "/" was rooted to the "public" directory. Luckily, my favicon works now. However, I seem to have broken the title in the process.